# Docker exits CMD on start

Tags: docker, playframework

I have a docker image that runs [play](https://www.playframework.com/) web application. In dockerfile there is CMD which starts the server and it waits until you hit Ctrl+D to exit. If I do:

```
docker run -d  -i -v
```

It works correctly - starts the server and waits for ctrl+D.

This is however not the case when i start the container:

```
docker start -i
```

Instead the server automatically stops:

```
--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] p.c.s.NettyServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)


[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Jul 27, 2016 11:54:13 AM <--- this indicates that the server was stopped.
```

How can I force docker start to not stop server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A docker container exits when its **main process finishes**. Without having an insight into your docker-file (I have no experience with the play framework), you need to make sure that at least one process stays alive.

You have a couple of options:

- Docker Way
  Try using `-it` like `docker run -it <your framework image> bash` to get into the container you are starting. This should keep your window open and allow you to run commands in the container.
- Docker "debug" way
  Try using the `docker inspect <your container>` (use `docker ps -a` to find your container) command to investigate why the container exited. In case you have a start script like start.sh you can try to add `while true; do sleep 1000;` done to keep the container up to investigate on what it was doing before it exited.
- Try using the one of the published docker images like - https://hub.docker.com/r/ingensi/play-framework/

P.S. I can not loose the feeling that you are new to docker and are mixing the `docker start` and the `docker run` command.