# Cannot keep the scala application up and running on docker

Tags: scala, docker, netty, dockerfile

I am trying to deploy a scala application on docker, but the server starts and stops immediately with the following log in the console,

--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] p.c.s.NettyServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9002

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

[info] p.c.s.NettyServer - Stopping server...

I start the server with the following command on docker,
activator -Dsbt.override.build.repos=true -Dsbt.repository.config=./repositories -Dsbt.log.noformat=true clean coverage "run 9002" &

Do you guys know how to keep the server from stopping until the container is killed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker exits CMD on start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38612349/docker-exits-cmd-on-start)

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the `&` in the command? This forks the command into the background and then the container just exits. You can probably solve this by just removing the `&`. Otherwise, some more information is needed.

Can you provide the `Dockerfile` including the full command used to start the container? Also, always posting versions of things is a good idea (what versions of Scala, Docker, etc.).

Comment: I am able to resolve this issue by compiling the application first and then deploying the application
1. activator -Dsbt.override.build.repos=true -Dsbt.repository.config=./repositories -Dsbt.log.noformat=true clean coverage dist
2. bin/test-project -Dhttp.port=9002 &